# Appium inspector not open getting instruments crash on startup

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am automating iPhone application on real devices, I am able to manually install application.

I setup ipa file and added udid in appium configuration but when launch Appium inspector getting below error message and inspector not launched. also I noticed that application getting installed using Appium.

```
 info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
 info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
 info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
 info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
  at 
 [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 20210.927 ms - 182
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here.

Thanks
Sadik

Comment: for me, i delete all the existing devices and than create new device through xcode. and than link the device like below: xcode>open developer tool>instruments>automation and than after showing the newly created device, just link it by clicking.

Comment: @noor I already tried with this options but not able to get devices under tool>instruments>automation

Comment: Give me a favour.. I will give detail tomorrow.